# How can I count @ViewBuilder Views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to to know how can I count my `inPutView` in this example of code, the code working like this, it takes some views and gave a background color and counts the count of view, thanks for help.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ModelView(inputView: {
            Text("Hello, world!").padding()
            Text("Hello, world!").padding()
        })
        
    }
}

struct ModelView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var inPutView: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping () -> Content) { self.inPutView = inputView }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            inPutView()
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        
        Text("count of inPutViews: 2").padding() // Here: How can I found out the count of inPutView?
        
    }
}
```

---

**update:**

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    var inputViews: [AnyView] = [AnyView(Text("Hello, world!").padding()), AnyView(Text("Hello, world!").padding())]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ModelView2(inputViews: inputViews)
        
    }
}

    struct ModelView2: View {
    var inputViews: [AnyView]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(inputViews.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                inputViews[index]
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)

        Text("count of inPutViews: \(inputViews.count)")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to detect the count if individual views inside a `@ViewBuilder` closure. The `@ViewBuilder` creates **one** resulting view and your `inPutView` is treated as a **single** view.

A possible solution is to pass the `[AnyView]` array as the input of `ModelView`. But then `AnyView` doesn't conform to `Hashable` nor `Identifiable`, so you can't use it in a `ForEach`.

In your case you can create a separate struct conforming to `Identifiable`:

```
struct AnyViewItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let view: AnyView
}
```

and populate `ModelView` with an array of `AnyViewItem`:

```
struct ModelView: View {
    var inputViews: [AnyViewItem]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(inputViews) {
                $0.view
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)

        Text("count of inPutViews: \(inputViews.count)")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in your main view like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ModelView(
            inputViews: [
                Text("Hello, world!").padding(),
                Text("Hello, world!").padding(),
            ]
            .map {
                AnyViewItem(view: AnyView($0))
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, in this case you can make `inputViews` an `[AnyView]` array and iterate through its `indices`:

```
ForEach(inputViews.indices, id: \.self) {
    inputViews[$0]
}
```

Comment: thanks, I made an update from your codes, could you see that? I think we do not need make another step to make AnyViewItem. is it ok?

Comment: @swiftPunk Yes, you're right, you can just use `indices` for this case. I think I was just thinking how it may be used in the future. I'll update my answer.

Comment: no please let it stay, it has rich code for others to use as well, thanks

Comment: @swiftPunk Ok, I kept the original solution and added your comment as an alternative.